# Search API Elastic Search index

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to call a remotely hosted elastic search index from Java and fetch the data from same index depending on some conditions.

Help me, I am new to Elastic search and it's indexing mechanism.

Comment: this can be answered in simple steps , well google has all the answers to this query.can be reopened to a healthy discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing would be you use the elasricsearch client for java. The maven dependency as follows with the right version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>${es.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Second create a Client using TransportClient by providing the appropriate host-id and port(9300 by default).

```
Client client = new TransportClient()
.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("host-ip-address", 9300));
```

Lastly query the result. For instance a match query would be as follows.

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("location", "india");
SearchResponse response = esClient.prepareSearch("index-name").setTypes("type-name")
    .setQuery(qb)
    .execute().actionGet();
```

Finally your response will have the required result from elasticsearch for all the document having india as the location.